# AWS cognito `connection pool shutdown`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

In my spring boot project, I am first creating a user pool in cognito and then adding a user to the user pool. when adding the user to user pool I need to create a `userPoolClient`

I am creating the user client with all the required params with

```
CreateUserPoolClientResponse response = cognitoClient.createUserPoolClient(clientRequest);
```

but its behaving strangely. when i am running the code its throwing `connection pool shut down` but when i run my code in debug mode with breakpoint, its able to create the `user pool client` successfully. I am not sure if creation of connection pool is async process and that's why with the debugger its getting some time before creating it?

Does anyone faced this issue? would appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running AWS SDK Java V2 for this use case. Here is the code for V2.

```
package com.example.cognito;

//snippet-start:[cognito.java2.user_pool.create_user_pool_client.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.CognitoIdentityProviderException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.CreateUserPoolClientRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.CreateUserPoolClientResponse;
//snippet-end:[cognito.java2.user_pool.create_user_pool_client.import]

/**
 * To run this Java V2 code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class CreateUserPoolClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <clientName> <userPoolId> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    clientName - the name for the user pool client to create.\n\n" +
                "    userPoolId - the ID for the user pool.\n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String clientName = args[0];
        String userPoolId = args[1];

        CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        createPoolClient (cognitoClient, clientName, userPoolId) ;
        cognitoClient.close();
    }

    //snippet-start:[cognito.java2.user_pool.create_user_pool_client.main]
    public static void createPoolClient ( CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient,
                                          String clientName,
                                          String userPoolId ) {

        try {

            CreateUserPoolClientResponse response = cognitoClient.createUserPoolClient(
                    CreateUserPoolClientRequest.builder()
                            .clientName(clientName)
                            .userPoolId(userPoolId)
                            .build()
            );

            System.out.println("User pool " + response.userPoolClient().clientName() + " created. ID: " + response.userPoolClient().clientId());

        } catch (CognitoIdentityProviderException e){
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[cognito.java2.user_pool.create_user_pool_client.main]
}
```

I just ran this in a unit test and it worked fine.

[image]

You can find this one and other code examples for this service here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/cognito

Comment: thanks. let me try.

Comment: Amazon recommends using V2 over V1. All V2 code has been tested many times in unit tests, etc.